# IF statement with IN Operator in PL/SQL Code

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to compare values (`VARCHAR2` with one of value from list) using `IN` operator. For example, value is A, list Values is B and C. Values is

Simple static code that works:

```
IF 'A' NOT IN ('B', 'C') THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In');
END IF;
```

Non-working dynamic code:

```
IF 'A' NOT IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM APEX_STRING.SPLIT('B:C', ':') ) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In');
END IF;
```

Getting an error:

```
Error at line 39/48: ORA-06550: line 20, column 67:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   . ) , @ with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
   minus partition start subpartition union where connect sample
The symbol "having" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

Can't understand where is mistake. In SQL query similar code with `IN` operator works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not set on the `IN` operator, I would always suggest to use `MEMBER OF` when doing anthing with apex_t_varchar2 (the result of `apex_string.split`).

Again, as Massi already pointed out, you can't use `SELECT` statements without `INTO`or defining a cursor. So we'll shorten it to just the split function.

In your case, you could write:

```
BEGIN
    IF 'A' NOT MEMBER OF (APEX_STRING.SPLIT('B:C', ':')) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use SELECT in operator IN. You must before execute query INTO a variable and use after in IF TEST.
For example with count function:

```
SELECT count(*)
  INTO my_var
  FROM APEX_STRING.SPLIT('B:C', ':')
 WHERE COLUMN_VALUE  = 'A';

IF my_var > 0  THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not');
ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In');
END IF;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mean I can't use it directly in PL/SQL Code? In SQL query it works. For Example: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' NOT IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM APEX_STRING.SPLIT('B:C', ':') ) THEN 'Not' ELSE 'In' END AS R FROM DUAL`. There is no more solutions for PL/SQL? For Example APEX_T_VARCHAR2 in IN operator?

Comment: Yes, you can't use directly in PL/SQL the SELECT STATEMENT with operator IN but you shoud always use by variable, function, procedure, etc. etc.

Comment: @ES the problem is the `select`, not the `in`. You can certainly use `select` within PL/SQL, but it needs to be part of a `select into` construction, or a loop, or declared as a cursor. There's no `expression in (subquery)` construction.